# How to pass $app to Class Function with Slim Framework for Rest in PHP

Tags: php, rest, scope, slim

I am using the slim framework, but having a scope problem. I am calling my functions using their class names in a string. I do not know how to pass $app to them. Here is my `$app->group` and `$app->get` lines:

```
$app->group('/user', function() use ($app, $log)    {

    //User Functions
    $app->get('/login', 'myAPI::userLogin');
    $app->get('/signup', 'myAPI::userSignUp');
    $app->get('/exists', 'myAPI::userExists');
    $app->get('/info', 'myAPI::userInfo' );

}
```

Here is my Class and Function: ($app does not exist because it is out of scope and I don't know how to access it so I can get the parameters)

```
class myAPI
{
    public static function userInfo()   {
        $app = Slim::getInstance(); // <-- this line does not work
        // Get Parameters
        $username = $app->request->get('username');
        $college = $app->request->get('college');
        $domain = $app->request->get('domain');

        $query = "Select * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        if(!$results = Database::instance()->get_results($query)){
            $results = array('error' => 'No results.');
        }

        return self::output($results);
    }
}
```

The entire file can be downloaded here:

http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/phpcode

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was pretty trivial. I changed the get calls to include there own function that calls the API methods in a similiar way, but now have a `use` statement to pass the `$app` scope to the function. This also requires that I pass it as a parameter so add the parameter to function as well.

I will write the code I used to correct this below:

My Slim `->group` and `->get` and function calls to API class methods:

```
$app->group('/user', function() use ($app, $log)    {

    //User functions
    $app->get('/info', function () use ($app) {myAPI::userInfo($app);});

}
```

My class function calls:

```
class myAPI
{
    public static function userInfo($app)   {
        // Get Parameters
        $username = $app->request->get('username');
        $college = $app->request->get('college');
        $domain = $app->request->get('domain');

        $query = "Select * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        if(!$results = Database::instance()->get_results($query)){
            $results = array('error' => 'No results.');
        }

        return self::output($results);
    }
}
```

Comment: That first line in `userInfo()` is reduntant.  Why are you passing `$app`, if you're gonna replace it by `Slim::getInstance();`

Comment: Also, make sure you have the `$app`, before passing it over in your `myAPI::userInfo($app);` call, because it seems like you're lossing it somewhere